# Python changing ClassA instance variables in ClassB

Tags: python, class, object, dill

I am trying to load a whole class instance via dill rather than dump and load each class variable one at a time.

Can anybody show me how to do this:

```
class Object(object):
    pass

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DATA = "Initial"

class ClassB:
    def __init__(self, CA):
        self.CA = CA

    def updateValue(self):
        #a = dill.load(ClassA.storage)
        a = Object()
        a.DATA = "new value"
        self.CA = a
        print self.CA.DATA

CA = ClassA()
CB = ClassB(CA)
CB.updateValue()
print CA.DATA
```

So that the output is:

```
new value
new value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking:

> Given object A and object B, how can I copy all of A's attributes to B in one step (or programatically)?

Naive approach:

```
B.__dict__ = dict(A.__dict__) # make a copy so objects don't share same dict
```

The problem with this approach is that it clobbers any preexisting attributes in B that did not exist in A. eg.

```
B.attr = "some value"
B.__dict__ = dict(A.__dict__)
print(hasattr(B, "attr")) # expect False
```

A better approach. This approach copies over A's attributes and leaves any attributes that exist on B, but not on A, alone.

```
B.__dict__.update(A.__dict__)
```

However, there are still problems if there are attributes on A's class and its parent classes that you want to copy over. But I think that's a different question.

Comment: I'm the dill author. I don't think you need serialization for this, unless you are looking to persist the objects across sessions. @Dunes shows the more appropriate route.

Answer (score 1):

In your `updateValue`

```
def updateValue(self):
    self.ca.DATA = "new value"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was can it be done without having to specify  'DATA'

Comment: What's your use case? I mean, what are you trying to achieve ? From the question it seems you want to change a member of a class. Am I getting it wrong ?